# Flatten the jsonb object that includes string and nested array in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the data in the table as:

```
column     |datatype
-----------|--------
id         | integer
name       | text
phone      | text
education  | jsonb
```

The example data is:

```
id    |   name   |   phone   |   data   |
------|----------|-----------|----------|
1     |Test User |78545254   | [[{"label": "Type", "value": "Graduate"}, {"From", "value": "01-04-2015"}, {"label": "To", "value": "21-04-2016"}],[{"label": "Type", "value": "Post Graduate"}, {"From", "value": "01-04-2015"}, {"label": "To", "value": "21-04-2016"}]] |
2     |Test Usr  |78545254   | [[{"label": "Type", "value": "Graduate"}, {"From", "value": "01-04-2015"}, {"label": "To", "value": "21-04-2016"}]] |
```

I want to make a query which can give me the output as:

```
id |  label             |     value       |
---|--------------------|-----------------|
1  | name               | Test User       |
1  | phone              | 78545254        |
1  | education_Type_1   | Graduation      |
1  | education_From_1   | 01-04-2015      |
1  | education_To_1     | 21-04-2016      |
1  | education_Type_2   | Post Graduation |
1  | education_From_2   | 01-04-2015      |
1  | education_To_2     | 21-04-2016      |
2  | name               | Test Usr        |
2  | phone              | 78545254        |
2  | education_Type_1   | Graduation      |
2  | education_From_1   | 01-04-2015      |
2  | education_To_1     | 21-04-2016      |
```

Can anyone please help me build such query?

Comment: Is you example data real data? or did you mock it up? It doesn't look like valid json.

Comment: Its not json, but its jsonb.